# Google's Firebase. Is it possible to send email notification if something was uploaded to storage?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have created an application that uploads pictures to google's Firebase and was wondering is it possible to create something that will send email notification with that file view link? Or should I create something in app that send email when picture has been uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write a Cloud Function that will be triggered (in the back-end, in  a "trusted environment") when a file is uploaded to Cloud Storage and sends a mail via Sendgrid (solution recommended by Firebase).

Have a look at:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events for Cloud Storage triggering

and at

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid for sending an email via Sendgrid.

Also, have a look at these official samples: [mail](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation) and [storage trigger](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/9bc244a6966036f93ac8417bd3f8426efa200797/quickstarts/thumbnails)

As a Google cloud platform user you get a free quota of 12000 mails a month with Sendgrid. See https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/sendgrid-app/sendgrid-email

Do not hesitate to ask for more help if you encounter difficulties in implementing/adapting the code of these examples to your case.

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if you could help me. I have managed to select image and upload to firebase but what I need is to capture picture and upload it to my own storage. Could you give me somekind of tips where to start or how to do it? Thank you for your time

Comment: @LukasŠliužas A search on Google will return several tutorial links! https://www.google.com/search?q=androir+firebase+storage+take+picture+and+upload

Comment: Yes, I did that. It is working. But how could I merge that with my own storage

Comment: I would suggest you create a new question with the code you have already written and the problem or difficulties you are encountering.